# Not able to update db table from one server to another server in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

i am writing a program which can update one DB table on another server . 
Assume like my program is on server 192.168.195.103 and from here i am trying to connect to DB server IP 54.246.193.86 and port no 1521. So  here i am getting struck , please help me folks on this.
But i am getting error at line 13 marked below as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adap
ter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:189)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:231)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:345)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:428)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.ja
va:515)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:345)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at Conn.main(Conn.java:13)




import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
class Conn {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
System.out.println("hid");
  // Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


DriverManager.registerDriver( new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

System.out.println("hidd222");      
 **LINE13** --->>Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
   ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@54.246.193.86:1521:ROW0", "azglobal_users_prd", "catcat1");
                        // @//machineName:port/SID,   userid,  password

 //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
   // ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//54.246.193.86:1521/ROW0", "azglobal_users_prd", "catcat1");

System.out.println("hidd");   
try {
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     try {
    String s="France";
   String d="update ogl_table_status set status = 1 where mc_name='"+ s +"'";
System.out.println(d);
       //ResultSet rset = stmt.executeUpdate(d);
  stmt.executeUpdate(d);
       try {
         //while (rset.next())
          // System.out.println (rset.getString(1));   // Print col 1
       } 
       finally {
         // try { rset.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
       }
     } 
     finally {
       try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
     }
   } 
   finally {
     try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is a network problem.

Comment: try `ping 54.246.193.86` and if might be disabled, try `telnet 54.246.193.86 1521`. If both operations time out, try with a sql editor or database connector developer like Toad, PL\SQL Developer or JDeveloper and see if you can connect. Most likely, a firewall configuration on your end or the database end is blocking your connection.

Comment: Maybe your connectionString is wrong, try this : `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//54.246.193.86:1521/ROW0", "azglobal_users_prd", "catcat1"`

Comment: @prabugp yup...your right about telnetting the Server IP..it is saying connection timeout... lemme first get it resolved by n/w team

Comment: @ArbnorZeqiri ..string is right..but em my connnection time ti that IP is getting out...so lemme first get it resolved then..will reach you again

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not configured the AWS security groups for your DB server to accept connections either on port 1521, or from your IP address.

Simply select "Security Groups" from the left hand menu from either EC2, or RDS (depending on how you started your DB), locate your security group and update accordingly.

Comment: Crollster.. if i ignore this DB communication gap and try to use JNI with adding static {
    try {
     System.load("C:/Windows/System32/marketRx.Framework.Data.dll");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }  in my code then also it is giving me..error   Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:/Windows/System32/marketRx
.Framework.Data.dll .... can help more on using DLL in java program